# Use FTPS (by sending AUTH TLS) with wget

Tags: ssl, ftp, wget, ftps

I am trying to download file from FTP server using `wget`:

```
wget --debug --no-passive-ftp --ftp-user=user --ftp-password=password ftp://server/file.gz file.gz
```

What I get is:

```
220 Private FTP server
Logging in as xxx ... 
--> USER xxx

331 Non-anonymous sessions must use encryption.

--> PASS xxx
Error in server response, closing control connection.
```

I am able to connect and download files from FTP server using FileZilla. In FileZilla I get this in log:

```
Response:   220 Private FTP server
Command:    AUTH TLS
Response:   234 Proceed with negotiation.
Status: Initializing TLS...
Status: Verifying certificate...
Status: TLS connection established.
Command:    USER xxx
Response:   331 Please specify the password.
Command:    PASS ******************
```

Download task must be executed on remote server where I cannot use FileZilla. How can I force `wget` to send `AUTH TLS` command before `USER xxx` command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `ftps://` URL:

```
wget ... --ftp-user=user --ftp-password=password ftps://server/file.gz file.gz
```